# UPDATE Adressen SET `Straße`=REPLACE(`Straße`,'\','');" - How to escape \ in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, macos, dbeaver

I am using the https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-replace-function.aspx but i can't replace: \

I am using DBeaver on MacOS.

Its working with other letters:

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
    productDescription = REPLACE(productDescription,
        'abuot',
        'about');
```

But this is not working:

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
    productDescription = REPLACE(productDescription,
        '\',
        '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash (`\`) using double backslash (`\\`):

```
UPDATE products SET productDescription = REPLACE(productDescription, '\\', '');
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63e6fc673f8eeee361a3ac392bb10027)

You can find a list with all special characters on [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) (Table 9.1 Special Character Escape Sequences).

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know, why i don't get it to work. I am sure your answer is right, but somehow i must make something wrong.

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes its working. I needed to escape more - since i called it with nodejs :D I needed to write 4 of \\\\. Thank you!